# Throwing exceptions two attitudes

Tags: java

I came from .net world.

I have some question about exceptions in java.

What is deference between two attitude of throwing exceptions:

```
public void f() throws Exception {
     //some logic
}
```

and this:

```
public void f() {
    //some logic
    throw new Exception();
}
```

When should I use first attitude and the second attitude?

Comment: Do it in the second way if you don't mind it not being valid Java.

Comment: The second is invalid. You want `throw [new Exception()]`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and `throws Exception` on the method signature, because you can't have an unhandled checked exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yep, that too.

Comment: @Michael I think you would be well-served by reading [the Oracle tutorial on exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). Your question suggests there are some important concepts that you've not understood (like `throw` vs `throws`; checked vs unchecked exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you need to specify how your method behaves. This includes exceptions that can possibly be thrown. To declare, that you method can that an exception, the `throws` keyword is used (as in your first Example).

Note that only Exceptions that derive from the `Exception` class must be depicted here (there are also `RuntimeExceptions` and other `Throwables` that do not need to be depicted. [More here](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/exceptions/throwable.html)).

To throw an Exception you need the keyword `throw` followed by the instance of any `Exception` (to be precise, you can throw any `Throwable`).

A valid method would be:

```
public void foo() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in using these two. Assuming the second method is without *s*. The first approach, `throws`, used in the method signature, denoting which Exception can possible be thrown by this method. You can declare multiple exception classes. For checked Exception, the caller can either handle this exception by catching it or can rethrow it by declaring another throws in method declaration.

`public void f()throws IOException, SQLException {
          //some logic
     }`

The second approach, using `throw` without *s* is used in any part of code followed by an instance whenever you need to throw a specific exception to the caller.

```
public void f(){  
  //some logic
 throw new ArithmeticException("sorry");  
}
```

You can get more information [throw and throws in Java](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/throw-throws-java/)